# Arduino 3 digit LCD calculator

Tags: arduino, lcd, calculator, keypad

We would like to build a calculator using Arduino which uses 3 digit LCD and a keypad similar to digital phones. (# for plus , * for minus) Which components and way is good enough to not to run out of I/O ports?

Comment: With some care, you can share either the rows or columns between the display and the keyboard.

Comment: thank you very much for all answers and comments. It is my bad to not be able to check here again. We have designed the board from scratch , using the same model atmel processor on arduino uno.

Answer (score 1):

Check this arduinoo calculator kit:
http://www.spikenzielabs.com/Downloadables/calc/CalcBuildInstructions.pdf
Software and hardware is open source. They manages to connect 17 buttons and 6 digits LED. Wiring and sketch is very easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Not know which arduino you use, or the total number of pins you need, the basic answer is Shift Registers or (i2c/spi) Port Expanders. More specialized versions would be 7 segment led drivers (if you are using led 7 segment displays obviously), and keypad matrix ICs. If you are using actual lcd displays, it would highly depend on the display and/or controller for the display.

Comment: He is probably looking for shields.